# Help for a pot rack on our apartment's kitchen wall

Tags: walls, mounting

I'd like to put this pot rack on our wall, can I just get anchors for the type of wall and for the correct weight? We've used it for over ten years on all kinds of walls that in some cases in our rental apartments were like old cardboard. This thing always stayed up. But this is our own apartment now that we've bought and I'd like to ask what the proper way is. In the past, as I said, I just went with the type of wall it was and the right weight in the anchors. There is a stud but not in a useful place. I think this wall is just plaster with some sort space in between. The total weight of the rack and all pans that will go on it (no pots) is 35lb. Maximum. And that's leaving room for an extra 5-7 lbs of pans that won't even fit anyway.

Thanks[image: Wall portion][image: Pot rack]

Comment: "Nothing parties like a rental." Sigh... If "slap it up with an anchor" has worked for the last 10 years, why do you suddenly think it won't work now? TBH, I'd arrange it so the top, center hole was centered over a stud and use a proper screw/lag bolt to hold that in, then anchors as necessary for the other two screws. But, it's _your_ place now (I presume "our own apartment" is in the NYC, "we've bought the place, but it's an apartment building" style meaning), so do whatever works.

Comment: @FreeMan It's not that I think it won't work now necessarily, it's that you go online to be prudent and to be open to possibly being wrong and asking how these things are done by people who really know what they're doing and get a range of opinions to see if what you're doing is wrong. And you get an overwhelming number of people telling you it's done a different way. Why have I never had it fall, on far less solid walls, I couldn't tell you. 
Unfortunately there isn't a stud in this short wall in a place that makes it possible to use it. for this application.